# how to create an app to block application installation by password

Tags: android-install-apk

I want to create an application that allows you to require a password to be entered in order for new application to be installed on android os.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. What you *could* do is set a broadcast receiver for app-installed. Every time a new app has been installed you could prompt for a password and if the wrong one is entered then you could uninstall the app.